# Sys.Date() with as.POSIXct()

Tags: r, posixct

Trying to get current date in a POSIXct class. I have tried the following:

> as.POSIXct(Sys.Date(), format = "%m/%d/%y", tz = "EST")

and got

[1] "2021-02-12 19:00:00 EST"

and I wish to only get the date without the time but in POSIXct class. For instance:

[1] "2021-02-12"

Answer (score 4):

Convert the Date class object to character first:

```
as.POSIXct(format(Sys.Date()))
## [1] "2021-02-13 EST"
```

Even shorter is:

```
trunc(Sys.time(), "day")
## [1] "2021-02-13 EST"
```

Note:

- POSIXct objects are stored internally as seconds since the Epoch and not as separate date and time so they always have times; however, if the time is midnight as it is here then it does not display when printed using the default formatting.
- if you only need the Date it is normally better to use `Date` class since using POSIXct class can result in subtle time zone errors if you are not careful and there is typically no reason to expose yourself to that potential if you don't need to.
- if  you change the session's time zone then it won't display without the time because midnight in one time zone is not midnight other time zones.

  ```
  x <- as.POSIXct(format(Sys.Date()))
  x
  ## [1] "2021-02-13 EST"

  # change time zone
  Sys.setenv(tz = "GMT")
  x
  ## [1] "2021-02-13 05:00:00 GMT"

  # change back
  Sys.setenv(tz = "")
  x
  ## [1] "2021-02-13 EST"
  ```

Comment: This is brillant!